# How to find the location of error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

How can I change the preferences in Xcode so that it highlights the exact location of an error like other programming environments instead of simply returning SIGABRT? Or is this not possible?

Comment: SIGABRT errors often disappear after cleaning all targets and restarting Xcode.

Comment: @Anne What I meant was that when say, a NSInvalidArgumentException occurs Xcode only highlights main.m, instead of where the error actually occurs like other programming environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode should already stop and show where execution is when a signal like SIGABRT occurs. (It does for me, without any special configuration).

> a NSInvalidArgumentException occurs Xcode only highlights main.m

It's not signals you need to catch for that, it's exceptions. Go to the breakpoint navigator and add an exception breakpoint.