# Xcode save and load image in Xcode iOS

Tags: xcode, image, load, save

Check my app if you don't really understand ( Quick Notes!) But here it goes. My app is a notes app so it allows the user to select from few different kinds of note colors and designs below. When the user selects one, it changes the note above to what ever they set it to. So i need a button that will save the picture they selected, and when the leave the view and come back they can click the load button and the same image they selected will appear. I am using Xcode 4.3. Thanks so much!

Here is my save code:

```
-(IBAction)save123456 {
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep;
    NSData *data;
    NSImage *noteview;

    [self lockFocus];
    rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[self frame]];
    [self unlockFocus];

    image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[rep size]] autorelease];
    [image addRepresentation:rep];

    data = [rep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];
    //save as png but failed
    [data writeToFile: @"asd.png" atomically: NO];

    //save as pdf, succeeded but with flaw
    data = [self dataWithPDFInsideRect:[self frame]];
    [data writeToFile:@"asd.pdf" atomically:YES];
}
And my load:
-(IBAction)load123456 {
NSImage loadedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: NSString* filePath]
}
```

I get so many error codes in my save. My image is called noteview. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try use instead

```
 [data writeToFile: @"asd.png" atomically: NO];
```

a code line

```
 [data writeToFile: @"asd.png" atomically: YES];
```

Some open source examples:

[AGSimpleImageEditorView](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGSimpleImageEditorView)

[image editors in iOS](https://github.com/search?q=image%20editor&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language=Objective-C)

[projects with work with Pictures](https://github.com/search?q=picture&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language=Objective-C)

Comment: Okay when i do this i get a lot of errors. I will put a star next to where the error is.                                                        -(IBAction)save123456 {
*    NSBitmapImageRep *rep;
    NSData *data;
*    NSImage *noteview;
    
*    [self lockFocus];
*    rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[self frame]];
 *   [self unlockFocus];
    
   * image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[rep size]] autorelease];
  *  [image addRepresentation:rep];

Comment: data = [rep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];
    //save as png but failed
    [data writeToFile: @"asd.png" atomically: YES];
    
    //save as pdf, succeeded but with flaw
    data = [self dataWithPDFInsideRect:[self frame]];
    [data writeToFile:@"asd.pdf" atomically:YES];
}
And the the load code is fine.

Comment: Try post here a errors. For some tip, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005317/how-to-find-the-location-of-error-in-xcode/11007493#11007493

Comment: They are all like use of undeclared. Do you think you could give me some demo code on how you would save and load an image? thanks